# How to integrate this function: $-\ln(2\sin(\frac x2))$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I have to find the fourier series for $f(x) = -\ln(2\sin(\frac x2)),\quad 0 \lt x \lt 2\pi$,
So I started by trying to solve for $a_0$ with $2\pi a_0=\int_0^{2\pi} -\ln(2\sin(\frac x2))dx$
I started to solve it using integration by parts by letting $u=-\ln(2\sin(\frac x2))$ and $dv=1dx$, I ended up doing integration by parts two more times after that and realized that I just kept going in circles. So what method can I use to solve this? What method would I also use to solve the integrals for $a_n$ and $b_n$ where the integrands would be $-\ln(2\sin(\frac x2))\cos(nx)$ and $-\ln(2\sin(\frac x2))\sin(nx)$?

Comment: the primitive function is the following $$i/3 \left( {\pi }^{2}+6\,\ln  \left( {{\rm e}^{i/2x}} \right) \ln 
 \left( 2 \right) +6\,\ln  \left( {{\rm e}^{i/2x}} \right) \ln 
 \left( \sin \left( x/2 \right)  \right) +3\, \left( \ln  \left( {
{\rm e}^{i/2x}} \right)  \right) ^{2}-6\,\ln  \left( {{\rm e}^{i/2x}}
 \right) \ln  \left( {{\rm e}^{i/2x}}+1 \right) -6\,\ln  \left( {
{\rm e}^{i/2x}} \right) \ln  \left( -{{\rm e}^{i/2x}}+1 \right) -3\,{
\it dilog} \left( -{{\rm e}^{ix}}+1 \right)  \right) 
$$

Comment: You can instead think about Fourier series on $[-\pi,\pi]$ with the corresponding translated function. Then your function is *even*, so it has only a cosine expansion.

Comment: so would I use $-ln(2sin(x/2))$ for $[0, \pi]$ and $ln(2sin((x-\pi)/2))$ for $[-\pi, 0]$?

Comment: No, I'm saying that if you can series expand $-\ln(2 \sin((x+\pi)/2))$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$ then you can shift back to series expand your function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**. One may recall the series expansion
$$
-\log (1-e^{-ix})=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{-inx}}n, \qquad 0<x<2\pi,
$$ 
and one may observe that we have
$$
\begin{align}
-\log (2 \sin (x/2))&=\Re \left(-\log\left(1-e^{-ix}\right)+i(x+\pi/2)\right),\quad 0<x<2\pi,
\end{align}
$$ giving

> $$
> -\log (2 \sin (x/2))=\Re \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{-inx}}n\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos (nx)}n, \quad 0<x<2\pi.
> $$

This may give the Fourier series you are looking for.

Comment: Minor typo: the first $e^{-inx}$ should just be $e^{-ix}$. +1, though.